# Get unknow content on web app

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome, web-applications

A few day ago (1 week). Sometime I get error:

I can't inspect it on chrome debugger (the unknow content). It never shows before.

**At '../home.html'** the unknow content came with **blue** background:

[image]

In another screen it was white:

**At '../another.html'**

[image]

**But I can still click on buttons which were hidden by this unknow content.**

So, I think new chrome version **(JS update)** or **new windows update** cause this error.

It happened on: CPU Pentium g3250, CPU i3 2100, CPU i7 4600U

On: CPU i5 7400 | 6400 work fine, nothing happened.

All run on windows 10

Chrome version was latest (67)

My webapp uses a lot of js function, but get 0 error, 0 warning for this bug.

When I click or do something (do more action), it happened, it did not show at start time (page load time).

Help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comment / remove **smoothscroll.js** lib and problem was solved!

[image]

[Here's](https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites) the lib that i've tried to use (SmoothScroll for websites v1.3.8 (Balazs Galambosi))